# "Начался" — ударение

Tags: орфоэпия

Моя мама всю жизнь говорила и продолжает говорить *н**а**чался.* Есть ли какие-то основания полагать, что раньше ударение в этом слове падало на первый слог или такой вариант был одним из двух? Или она просто привыкла к просторечному употреблению?

Answer (score 4):

Здесь было бы уместно вспомнить лекции А. Зализняка о тенденциях смещения ударения в русском языке. Правда, я не готов дать сейчас ни ссылки, ни краткое описание основных идей. Но могу напомнить, что в прошлом ударение в глаголах на **-ся** мужского рода падало на последний слог: *бралсЯ, взялсЯ, клялсЯ, налилсЯ, отнялсЯ, поднялсЯ, приподнялсЯ, снялсЯ, унялсЯ* и т.п. Сейчас такое ударение в большинстве случаев считается устаревшим. Исключения: *занялся, начался, принялся, заперся, отперся*. Из всех этих исключений только глаголы **начался** и **отперся** держатся до последнего (в остальных уже допустимы другие варианты ударения). Поэтому я бы предположил, что ваша мама просто немного опередила время :)

Мне самому ближе произношение нАчался, но это, вероятно, под влиянием творчества В.С. Высоцкого, который во всех песнях употреблял только такое ударение (например: "Роман так странно нАчался" или "Ну что ж такого — нАчался запой").

Comment: Спасибо, grizzly!

Answer (score 3):

Реальное произношение может иметь варианты, но они  **ненормированные.**
На сайте Грамота.ру стоит одно ударение (началсЯ), в словаре Резниченко – тоже.
[http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=ударение+в+слове+начался](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5+%D0%B2+%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5+%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%81%D1%8F)

Вопрос № 244269

Здравствуйте! Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно ставится ударение в слове начался.  Ответ справочной службы русского языка. Правильно: началсЯ. Пожалуйста, пользуйтесь электронными словарями, размещенными на нашем портале.

Вопрос № 235620

Правильное ударение в слове начался. Ответ справочной службы русского языка. Ударение падает на последний слог: началсЯ.

Еще бокалов жажда просит

Залить горячий жир котлет,

Но звон брегета им доносит,

Что новый ***началсЯ*** балет.

Comment: Я не сомневаюсь, что во времена А.С. только так и говорили, но сам по себе четырёхстопный ямб в нерифмованной позиции это никак доказывать не может :)

Comment: Спасибо! В ямбах не специалист, но по аналогии со второй строкой вижу: *залИть горЯчий жир котлЕт,* поэтому просится как раз *что нОвый нАчался балЕт.*

Comment: Поддерживаю _Sharon_ (я уже достаточное время принципиально не отвечаю на вопросы, но — наблюдаю). Эх-эх.. Не нужно быть специалистом в ямбах — можно **просто послушать** удивительного Юрского (около 9.50): _**новый начался́ балет**_. (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7UwuVqvbnRA)

Answer (score 2):

Это один из глаголов,  у которых при образовании возвратной формы ударение в прошедшем времени смещается на окончание (*начался́, начали́сь, начало́сь*).
http://www.239.ru/sites/default/files/userdata/slovnik-orfoepicheskiy.pdf

Таковы рекомендации произношения данного слова; высказывается предположение, что положение ударения может измениться со временем: https://aif.ru/society/education/na_chalsya_nacha_lsya_ili_nachalsya_kak_pravilno

**P.S.** Сам я варьюрую ударение между первым и последним слогом в зависимости от контекста ("на́чался шторм", но "спектакль начался́" - возможно, на выбор влияет пресловутое логическое ударение).

Comment: Интересно, спасибо, Александр! По ссылке только говориться не что норма "началсЯ" сложилась постепенно, а что, наоборот, она такой была, а сейчас от неё иногда отступают.

Comment: Спасибо, я изменил комментарий к этой статье. Там попытка линвиста подвести слово под общую тенденцию, но отвлеченные примеры не убеждают,

Comment: Да, мне тоже кажется, что с этим словом может быть по-другому или даже наоборот.